# How to publish a website built by HTML and PHP?

Tags: php, server, web-hosting, host

I built a website (localhost) using PHP and HTML through XAMPP. Now, I want to publish it online (webhost), available to everyone. What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need some type of webserver. A webhotell or similar which manages all the server configuration is usually the best way to start.

Comment: You would also need a domain, so people can find your website. How about this one: https://www.freehosting.com/free-hosting.html (but there are loads of alternatives)

Comment: hey guys isn't this question off topic here? It seems to have more to do with server and networking right?

Answer (score 0):

First you need a host to upload your files. For this purchase hosting space from godaddy, bluehost or someother provider. You need to purchase a domain too. After domain and hosting space, if you have purchase linux hosting, then 90% chance is that you will get a cpanel. So log into your cpanel then navigate to 'public_html'. Inside this, using some ftp client like filezilla, or cpanel's build in upload feature, upload all your files. If your website needs a database, then you need to create a database, add database user and password using database wizard tools in cpanel.

When you will purchase a hosting, these things will be very clear once you login and expore a little.

Answer (score 0):

Moving a website to another host consists of the following steps:

- Moving the website's files.
- Moving the website's database(s) (if any).
- Configuring your application to work at the new host.
- Pointing your domain's DNS to the new host.

A more detailed breakdown of these steps can be found below:
Transferring the files to the new host

The most convenient way to transfer your website's files to your new web hosting account is via FTP. You should connect to your hosting account and download the files locally to your computer. Then you have to upload them to your new hosting account's main folder (usually public_html, www or httpdocs).

More information on how to use FTP can be found in our FTP tutorial.
Transferring the website's databases

You have to export the database content from your old hosting account (usually into an SQL file), create a new database at your new hosting company and import the information in it. For detailed information on how to import/export databases via phpMyAdmin you can refer to this tutorial.
Application setup on the new host

This really depends from the website application that you are using. For step-by-step instructions on how to reconfigure some of the most popular applications

Comment: He doesn't have an old hosting account. He's been testing it on localhost, now he's creating his first hosted site.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out https://www.heroku.com/. The website will update as you push your code to the git. It's free, easy to use and good for small project.